# .NET 2012 Professional -> Couldn't process file xxxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Using VS 2012 Professional.  Can't build a winforms application.

Receiving error:  `Couldn't process file xxxx.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file.  Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files`.

I tried adding to the local intranet -> `file://computername` like example below but didn't work.  I also tried to right click, properties, but there was NO unblock checkbox.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/291761/couldnt-process-file-abcresx-due-to-its-being-in-t.html

Any idea how to resolve.  This is a production problem for me.